# Ubuntu won't detect my Nvidia Geforce 1050

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xserver

I recently bought a new laptop, an ASUS F570Z, which has a dual GPU (the AMD Vega GPU and the dedicated Geforce GTX 1050. Unfortunately, don't matter what I do, Ubuntu won't use the Geforce or even give me the option to use it, not even opening XSERVER as seen in the images:

[XSERVER BLANK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuF72.jpg)
[Nvidia smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKkUE.png)

I have tried to:

Disable the secure boot;

Purge the drivers and reinstall them;

Purge the drivers and install other version;

Reinstall the OS

Nothing worked... I am at my wits end here. :(

Comment: Dual graphics AMD+NVIDIA doesn't seem to be suuported by Linux yet.

Comment: But the AMD is not a separated GPU but an integrated one in the processor...

Comment: That's the problem. It is switchable graphice. The Nvidia ai not a full feature adapter, but a GPU working together with the intgrated one. This is not handled properly yet. `nvidia-prime` can't manage it.

Comment: So... There is no way to solve it?

Comment: At least I don't know a solution. Sooner or lated it will be fixed. Maybe someone has found a workaround.

Comment: Thanks anyway....